# Sql Server - help Dateadd function (Conversion issue)

Tags: sql-server

I've the following problem:

I need to calculate a date using dateadd function.

```
dateadd(d,delay),CONVERT(DATE,Started,105))
```

delay is taken from a different table than started, and its in numeric format

the problem is I receive this type of error:

> *Messaggio 241, livello 16, stato 1, riga 14
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

I then tried to do something like:

```
dateadd(d,CAST(delay AS NUMERIC(8)),CONVERT(DATE,Started,105))
```

> resulting in the same error :(

Anyone can please help me?

Comment: When you say numeric format what do you mean 20170130 or 30012017 or 01302017?

Comment: Questions like this should include example input data, so readers have something worth speculating about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is very clear. There are values in the Started column that cannot be converted to date using the style you provided. Such is the path your table designer chose when choosing to store dates as strings. Now you need to either clean up the data (better yet - clean and convert the column to the correct datatype) or you write your queries to avoid the bad rows. So how do you do that?

You could (and should) get into the habit of searching the internet for answers. This question is posted daily somewhere. Assuming you have a current version of sql server, you can use the following to find the "bad" rows.

```
select * from dbo.mytable as tbl where try_convert(date, tbl.Started, 105) is null
order by tbl.Started;
```

And you can adapt that logic to avoid bad rows very easily.